# iTunes update locations on Win 10

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup, windows

Recently I needed to update the iOS to the newest 16.4 version. From what I've seen, hope I am not wrong, on iOS the downloads remains in the phone consuming system memory location.

An alternative is to use iTunes, but here, no matter where you have installed iTunes on your PC, it might be a chance at some point you will not have sufficient space (on C: drive) for update, resulting in unable to move forward with your updates.

It seems that iOS update via iTunes requires three different locations on Windows 10:

1. for DMG files: `C:\ProgramData\Apple Computer\iTunes\ [device] Temporary Files`
2. for Backup: `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup`
3. for new iOS: `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates`

For the last two, I solved it with `mklink` shortcut to another drive, but in case of the first one, I have not tried that way as iTunes creates n [device] Temporary Files in the moment of the update and after that it removes those directories.

Do you think might work as well with `mklink`?

Reference to the thread from Apple community, [C:\ProgramData\Apple Computer\iTunes taking up too much space, can I delete anything in here?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250987327)